# How to fix "Error: `path` does not exist:" and "Contains magic number?"

Tags: r, csv, xls

I'm trying to read a .xls file but it is not working. It either says that the file-path does not exist, that the file is corrupted or that it contains a magic number. When manually selecting the file it also does not work, but I can open the excel file just fine.

I was initially trying to convert the xls file to CSV and reading it using `read.csv`, then I started using `read_excel` directly with the xls file

```
load("~/Downloads/Crime2018EXCEL/noncampusarrest151617.xls")
```

> Error in load("~/Downloads/Crime2018EXCEL/noncampusarrest151617.xls") :
>         bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In grepl("RD[ABX][2-9]\n", magic) :
>         input string 1 is invalid in this locale
>       2: In grepl("RD[ABX][2-9]\r", magic) :
>         input string 1 is invalid in this locale
>       3: file ‘noncampusarrest151617.xls’ has magic number '������������������������'
>         Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated

```
crimestat<-read_xls("oncampuscrime151617.xls") #You might need to change the filepath
```

> Error: `path` does not exist: ‘oncampuscrime151617.xls’

Comment: Try `read_xls("~/Downloads/Crime2018EXCEL/noncampusarrest151617.xls")`. `load` is for R-objects (e.g. ending with .rda). You need to specify the full path where you saved the xls file, or save the file in the current working directory (Check `get_wd()` to figure this out), then you can use your second code.

Comment: get_wd() returns the R studio workspace directory. Using get_wid() will help to get a clear understanding where your workspace is located. Since read_excel() method reads the excel file from the current working directory. So if your current workspace directory is different from where you trying to read the excel data file, R Studio will give a path not found error.